# git checkout and go back to last commit after pushing changes

Tags: git, version-control, github

When i was on point D in my project I've made some changes to my project and push several commit (E,F,G,H) to git so i am in point H.
Now i have to make new change (I) and push them to git and deploy but i don't want my older commit (E,F,G,H) to be deployed.
I want to go back to D do my change(I) and deploy it without losing my old commits (E,F,G,H) then continue working on my project from point H.
 i only have one branch MASTER

I know i can do a git checkout H to go back to point H.
I know it is too late for a stash since changes has been commited (E,F,G,H) ....

I.e.

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H
             \             /
              I ----------
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

```
git checkout [sha for d] -b [branch name]
[make your changes]
[git add your changes]
[git commit]
[push branch]
[deploy the branch]
git checkout - # checks out back to the last checkout ref
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all commits A to H exist and you are at point H (i.e. HEAD of master, because you state you only have one branch), you could try:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~4           // Rolls you back to working state of D
git checkout -b branch_for_i      // Digress work from D on a new branch

** Make necessary changes for I

git commit                        // Commits changes required for I
git push origin branch_for_i      // Pushes up changes done for I
git checkout master               // Back to the branch with H as HEAD
git reset --hard HEAD             // Puts you back into the working state at H
```